# Symfony2 Dependency Injection to custom/business classes

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I didn't find similar questions/solutions Googleing, or on Stackoverflow, so here I am, in need for help.
I'm porting a PHP project from a custom framework to the Symfony framework (v2.5) which had it's custom dependency injection (based on class reflection). Many of the business logic classes have injected properties and I'm interested if there's a way to do something similar in Symfony without declaring those classes as services, because some of the classes are used for temporary holding/manipulating content coming from 3rd party endpoints and I need different instances of them.

More precisely is there a way to use Dependency Injection in combination with instantiating objects using the new keyword. So if I needed a new class that's dependent on logger or a validator, how could I do something like this.

Content class that I want to solve dependency injection for:

```
class Content extends SomeObject
{
    private $pictureUrl;
    ...

    public __construct(array $array = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($array);
    }

    public setPicture(...\Picture $picture)
    {
        // what's the best way to inject/enable this into my class
        $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($picture->getUrl());
        ...
        $this->pictureUrl = $picture->getUrl();
    }

    ...
}
```

The class that instantiates the previous class (in this particular case this could be a service, but there are other cases where this is another business logic related class):

```
class EndpointService extends Service
{
    ...

    public fetchContent()
    {
        $dataArray = $this->endpoint->fetch();
        $contentArray = array();

        foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
            $content = new Content(array());
            $content->setPicture($value->picture);
            ...
            $contentArray[$key] = $content;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**Note**: If there are logical/syntactical errors please ignore them, this is an example through which I demonstrate my problem, and is a distant abstraction from my code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that your `Content` is a model, and that the validation should be done in the `EndpointService` class.

You might consider refactoring so that the validator can be injected to the `Service` parent class that `EndpointService` inherits from, if you don't want to inject it to the `EndpointService` directly.

```
class EndpointService extends Service
{
    protected $validator;

    public __construct(Validator $validator) {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    ...

    public fetchContent()
    {
        $dataArray = $this->endpoint->fetch();
        $contentArray = array();

        foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
            $content = new Content(array());
            $errors = $this->validator->validate($value->picture->getUrl());
            $content->setPicture($value->picture);
            ...
            $contentArray[$key] = $content;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

And in your config:

```
// config.yml
services:
    app.endpoint_service:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\External\EndpointService
        arguments: [@validator]
```

Comment: That's a valid point, thanks for that, I will proceed according to your advice. But what if I still want to do dependency injection in similar cases. Are there any valid reasons for that, i.e. I want to use the logger or something similar, in a business class that's not a service.

P.S. I'd like to upvote you but my reputation isn't enough for that.

Edit: accidentaly hit enter before the end of the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote sentiment; I appreciate it! Re: injecting into non-service classes... you might consider having those classes extend [http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAware.html](Container Aware). Not sure if that's best practice though. What's keeping you from making those classes into services? I didn't understand how their status as "temporary / holding" objects interfered with that.

Comment: Well not all classes correspond to the service paradigm, a cursor class (for pagination of content) for example is what I mean, and some classes that are used to get the 3rd party content to client side (similar to Entities but won't be persisted). 
I'm kinda searching for ways to tackle the project since it's rather large and has a different kind of Dependency injection (reflection based), which is very different from Symfony's own DI system.
As you said I should reconsider my architecture and I'll reshape it based on Symfony practices as much as I can. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

I see one way you could do it, by passing the `validator` depedency to your `EndpointService` through dependency injection. You could then pass it to the new `Content`.

```
class EndpointService extends Service
{
    ...
    public function construct($validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }


    public fetchContent()
    {
        $dataArray = $this->endpoint->fetch();
        $contentArray = array();

        foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
            $content = new Content($this->validator, array());
            $content->setPicture($value->picture);
            ...
            $contentArray[$key] = $content;
        }
    }
    ...
}

class Content extends SomeObject
{
    private $pictureUrl;
    ...

    public __construct($validator, array $array = null)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;

        parent::__construct($array);
    }

    public setPicture(...\Picture $picture)
    {
        // what's the best way to inject/enable this into my class
        $errors = $this->validator->validate($picture->getUrl());
        ...
        $this->pictureUrl = $picture->getUrl();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah but what if the class wasn't a service, how would I tackle the problem then? 
The "top" class will probably be a service, but do I want to pass 5-10 dependencies to the newly created classes to fill their dependencies?

Comment: It's common to define lots of services and then pass those services into another service. (Yo dawg - heard you like services)